# Automate database conversion from NAD83 to Web Mercator

Tags: coordinate-system, database, web

A NAD83 database is updated daily while a Web Mercator clone is only update when time is available. Looking to automate this process of

- Copying Layers
- Projecting them to Web Mercator
- Placing in correct .SDE

What would be the best way to do this? FME, model builder, python?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Esri software?  If so, take a look at this question:  [Can I copy an entire geodatabase with relationship classes and domains and reproject all feature classes from wgs84 to state plane?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/18094/653)?  It's a similar situation, specifically, see of the link in my answer (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/18108/653) which walks you through creating a replica geodatabase in a different spatial reference.  You could then use GDB replication to update the 'clone' database.